# How to get the newest API version of Azure Resources

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

How can I find out the newest apiVersion for Azure Resources.
I need them for my ARM Template.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For example for Storage accounts just use Powershell with.

**For Azure AZ:**

```
(Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Storage).ResourceTypes
```

For Azure RM:

```
(Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Storage).ResourceTypes
```

And then look for "storage accounts"

Comment: Is this an answer or an update to your question? If the latter, delete this answer and update your question instead. If the former, then make it clearer how this is an answer.

Comment: This is an answer. I had a lot of struggle to get this right. That's why I thought this PowerShell command could be useful to other devs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what we used to get the most recent API version available for application gateways.

```
$MostRecentApiVersion = ((Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq applicationGateways).ApiVersions[0];
```